# NameError: name 'firebase' is not defined - Firestore GeoPoint

Tags: python, firebase, geopoints

There are a lot of questions with similar title but I'm unable to figure out why firebase is not working. I've installed `pip install --upgrade firebase-admin` and everything is working fine but when I try to write `GeoPoint` I get this error on line:

```
position = firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(38.895242, -77.031256)
```

The error is:

> NameError: name 'firebase' is not defined

I've imported

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
import os
```

Comment: Follow this example : https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/blob/master/tests/test_firestore.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do:

```
import firebase
```

You are getting the error because you didn't import firebase and Python can't find it in its namespace.

Better still, do:

```
position = firestore.GeoPoint(38.895242, -77.031256)
```

This is because you already imported firestore.